# Visual Studio 2015: Error C2679 binary '>>': no operator found

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So here is my problem... I've been getting this error when I try to write to a .txt file in Visual Studio. In the command prompt, it gives me this error:
**"c:\users\carter\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JournalEntry\Debug\JournalEntry.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**.

This is the error I get in Visual Studio:
**Error C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [24]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)**  on line 18.

My program name is JournalEntry.cpp and all I am trying to do is write to a file called Journal.txt

Here's my code:

```
// JournalEntry.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream myJournal;
    myJournal.open("Journal.txt");
    if (myJournal.is_open())
    {
        myJournal >> "This is my first line! ";
        myJournal.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Error opening file ";
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `operator<<`, not `operator>>`.

```
myJournal << "This is my first line! ";
          ~~
```

Comment: If it helps to make sense of them, always follow the arrow direction. Are you trying to pipe content into myJournal, or out of myJournal into the output? The >> operator is often used to send content from an input stream (like std::cin) into a variable/output stream :)